# como faço para alterar a senha do meu root no windows?

Tags: mysql

eu perdi a senha do root que eu coloquei quando eu instalei o MySQL,porém não sei como faço para resetar/alterar sem saber a senha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pare o *MySQL* completamente. Isto pode ser feito acessando a janela Serviços do *Windows XP*, *Windows Server 2003* e afins, onde você pode parar o serviço *MySQL*.
- Abra o prompt de comando digitando `cmd` dentro da janela de *executar*. Dentro dele navegar até a pasta *bin* do *MySQL*.
  Ex: `C:\mysql\bin` usando o comando `cd`.
- Execute o seguinte comando no prompt de comando:
  `mysqld.exe-u root - skip-grant-tables`
- Deixe o prompt de comando atual como está, e abra um novo prompt de comando.
- Vá até a pasta *bin* do *MySQ*L, Ex: C:\mysql\bin usando o comando `cd`.
  Digite `mysql` e pressione *Enter*.
- Agora você deve ter o prompt de comando do *MySQL* funcionando. Digite `use mysql;` para selecionar o banco de dados `mysql`.
- Execute o seguinte comando para atualizar a senha:
  `UPDATE user SET Password = PASSWORD ( 'NOVA_SENHA') WHERE User = 'root';`

> Fonte: [Resetando senha root do MYSQL no WINDOWS XP/server 2003](https://aventurasphp.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/resetando-senha-root-do-mysql-no-windows/)